# NullInjectorError: No provider for custom component - Adding to providers doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am having errors thrown when I am attempting tests...

I have read many similar related issues, but adding my custom LoginComponent to app.module.ts providers doesn't help? It is already in the imports section.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**login.component.spec.ts** (summarised)

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {LoginComponent} from './login.component';
import {FormsModule, NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {AuthService} from "../../services/auth/auth.service";

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
   beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));

    it('Attempt login with various invalid forms', 
      inject([LoginComponent, AuthService],
      (loginComp: LoginComponent, authServ: AuthService) => {

    // Testing stuff here

    }));

}
```

Comment: What is the actual error and where do you get it ?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to resolve the issue by discovering I needed to place my LoginComponent in both the `declarations` & `providers` section.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [LoginComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
      providers: [LoginComponent]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  }));
```